# Anomaly with Ruby Date.parse

Tags: ruby, date

I've found a strange behavior in Ruby's Date.parse wondering if someone could shed light on.

Today's date is 17 Oct 2011.

```
irb(main):027:0> Date.parse("11-20").to_s
=> "2011-10-11"
irb(main):028:0> Date.parse("11/20").to_s
=> "2011-11-20"
irb(main):029:0> Date.parse("1-20").to_s
=> "2011-10-20"
irb(main):032:0> Date.parse("1/20").to_s
=> "2011-01-20"
irb(main):030:0> Date.parse("9-20").to_s
=> "2011-10-20"
irb(main):035:0> Date.parse("9/20").to_s
=> "2011-09-20"
irb(main):031:0> Date.parse("9-10").to_s
=> "2011-10-10"
irb(main):033:0> Date.parse("9/10").to_s
=> "2011-09-10"
irb(main):042:0> Date.parse("1-20-1997").to_s
ArgumentError: invalid date
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/date.rb:956:in `new_by_frags'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/date.rb:1000:in `parse'
        from (irb):42
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/date.rb:1578
irb(main):043:0> Date.parse("1/20/1997").to_s
=> "1997-01-20"
```

I'm not sure how it's interpreting the hyphen versus the slash. The slash behavior makes perfect sense to me. But the hyphen behavior is odd. What's parse doing in the hyphen case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Date.parse` internally uses a method called `_parse`, which you can see here:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-_parse

Your last example works if you put the year in front:

```
Date.parse("1997-1-20") #=> "1997-01-20"
```

This makes sense if you look at the default argument to `Date.parse`, which is `str='-4712-01-01'`. The hyphen form without a year is weird and I personally wouldn't use it.

Comment: Thanks. The description for "parse" says that it applies a "heuristic" algorithm to figure out what date you mean. Although I agree that mm-dd format is probably not common, I wasn't finding their heuristic algorithm very accurate in determining what one must mean by "9-20". It doesn't seem that ambiguous to me. I would have expected either 2011-09-20, or maybe 2020-09-01. But 2011-10-20 took me by surprise.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look in to using the [chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic) gem.